# Params::Validate callback failure handling

Tags: perl, validation, parameters

I am using `Params::Validate` module in my function. For one of the option, O am validating using a callback. Now I need to catch this failure and replace it with some custom message. How can this be achieved? I tried using on_fail option, but it did not catch the error.

Comment: Showing code would be more helpful for you to get answer.

Answer (score 1):

[Params::Validate](https://metacpan.org/pod/Params::Validate#Callback-Validation) will throw a *generic error* if you return a false value. To supply your own error message, simply let the callback `die`.

> The callback should return a true value if the value is valid. If not, it can return false or die. If you return false, a generic error message will be thrown by Params::Validate.

The docs also give a nice code example.

> ```
> validate(
>     @_,
>     {
>         foo => {
>             callbacks => {
>                 'smaller than a breadbox' => sub { shift() < $breadbox },
>                 'green or blue'           => sub {
>                     return 1 if $_[0] eq 'green' || $_[0] eq 'blue';
>                     die "$_[0] is not green or blue!";
>                 }
>             }
>         }
>     }
> );
> ```

Comment: I have returnObj which should have custom message, I dont want to die in the same function rather return the returnObj.
 validate(

Comment: @bestrahul21 I don't understand what you are saying.